# Обновление данных в DataBase через формы WTForms и flask-sqlalchemy Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

**Дано:**

*Flask, wtforms, flask-sqlalchemy*

**Класс базы данных:**

```
# офисы
class Offices(db.Model):
    off_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    off_office_name = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True, unique=True)
    off_office_short_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)

    off_admin = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('admins.a_id'))
    off_input_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

**Класс формы:**

```
class FormOfficeEdit(Form):
    form_office_name = StringField('Название офиса: ')
    form_office_short_name = StringField('Короткое название офиса: ')
```

**HTML-вывод формы**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            </br></br></br></br></br></br>
            <h1 class="display-5">Изменить</br>наименование офиса</h1>
            </br></br>
            <form action="{{ url_for('forms.edit_office', id=id) }}" method="post">
                {% for field in form_office_edit %}
                    <div class="form-field">
                        {{ field.label(class='control-label') }}
                        {{ field(class='form-control') }}
                        </br>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Основной обработчик:**

```
@forms.route('/edit_office/<int:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_office(id):
    offices_list = Offices.query.filter_by(off_id=id).all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms_office_edit = FormOfficeEdit(formdata=request.form, obj=offices_list)
        forms_office_edit.populate_obj(offices_list)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('ok.html')

    forms_office_edit = FormOfficeEdit()
    forms_office_edit.form_office_name.data = offices_list[0].off_office_name
    forms_office_edit.form_office_short_name.data = offices_list[0].off_office_short_name

    return render_template('forms_office_edit.html', id=id, form_office_edit=forms_office_edit)
```

**Что ожидается:** из строки адреса функция получает уникальный ID, по которому находит запись в базе данных. Если это первичное обращение, то в формы получают значения из базы данных и выводят их пользователю. Пользователь вносит корректировки, после чего нажимает кнопку и данные в DataBase обновляются.

**Что происходит:** запись в базе данных находится, значения в поля при первичном обращении подставляются. Но. После нажатия на кнопку происходит вот такое вот:

```
AttributeError
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'form_office_name'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поправить/решить задачу? Заранее признателен!

Answer (score 0):

Решил путём изменения в части **"if"**:

```
@forms.route('/edit_office/<int:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_office(id):
    offices_list = Offices.query.filter_by(off_id=id).all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        offices_list[0].off_office_name=request.form['form_office_name']
        offices_list[0].off_office_short_name=request.form['form_office_short_name']
        db.session.commit()

        return render_template('ok.html')

    forms_office_edit = FormOfficeEdit()
    forms_office_edit.form_office_name.data = offices_list[0].off_office_name
    forms_office_edit.form_office_short_name.data = offices_list[0].off_office_short_name

    return render_template('forms_office_edit.html', id=id, form_office_edit=forms_office_edit)
```

Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но главное — работает.